# How to extract metrics for gin (golang) in opentelemetry standard?

Tags: go, newrelic, go-gin, open-telemetry

I am working on observability and want to extract metrics related to gin. How can I extract metrics for gin (golang) in opentelemetry standard?

I went through opentelemetry-go-contrib, but it seems gin metrics is not supported, need help to implement metrics for gin.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this library. https://github.com/technologize/otel-go-contrib/tree/main/otelginmetrics.

```
import "github.com/technologize/otel-go-contrib/otelginmetrics"

router.Use(otelginmetrics.Middleware("your-sevice"))
```